# Chrome, Firefox deny image in popup; IE11, Edge fine with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a JavaScript/jQuery application that dynamically creates a catalog of my film collection, based upon a JSON file. For example, if you click the Titles button, the space below the button fills with all titles in the collection. Each title line also includes a link that uses the serial number as link context, providing a small body of film information that appears within a new window (=popup). All browsers (IE11, Edge, Firefox, Chrome) behave similarly to this point.

IE11 and Edge also show a JPEG image at the bottom of that film data, where that image is a link to another JavaScript application on my server that shows the JPEG image (up to) full screen.

Chrome does not acknowledge the JPEG image at all. Firefox shows an outline of the image but does not show the image nor acknowledge the link that it is to the other JS application.

I have gone through Chrome settings enabling my site for any action Chrome specifies. No change.

Similarly for Firefox. No effect.

The attached photo shows how the Microsoft browsers display my intended effect.

Any idea what browser rule I'm violating here?
[image]

4 Feb 2016  I'm adding this link to the application discussed as it is running on my server, which therefore allows access to both the JavaScript and JSON code. Although this is a private application of no use to anyone but myself I cannot understand why the techniques used operate only within the two Microsoft browsers. A Mac-using friend confirmed today that Firefox doesn't show the image, and Safari won't even enable the links on the first page! If there is something I'm doing wrong here, I'd love to know what it is!

http://www.michaelbroschat.com/film/discCatalog.html

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Are the images on your local computer?

Comment: Please include some code

Comment: I'll repeat that the app works perfectly in two browsers, so obviously all the pieces are present.